# View twitter feeds without sign in

Tags: iphone, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to make display tweets of a specific account, I have created application on twitter with consume key and secret key, but it requires access token, I have searched and found that user have to login but actually I want my app just to view tweets not signing in. !

Comment: my suggestion is to show your desired accounts tweet into UIWebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple "class" [AFTweetFetcher](https://github.com/austinfitzpatrick/AFTweetFetcher)

".. retrieving tweets from twitter using their new 1.1 API without requiring the user to authenticate.."

```
+(void) getMostRecentTweetFor:(NSString*) account then:(AFSingleTweetBlock) block;

/**
 *  Retrieves the most recent #{number} tweets for the given account then calls the callback passing
 *  an array of tweet objects.
 */
```

Comment: Thank you :), but there's one more question after receiving the array of tweets I want to extract the body to display in table, how can I extract it from AFTweet as I retrieve 50 tweets and AFTweet not including in the call back

Answer (score 0):

you should be using the widget provided by the twitter that shows the tweets

go to twitter login with your account go to settings> widgets
you can create the desired height and width of the widget.

and u can show it in your webview.

Comment: I want to display other account not mine, and I don't want to use his credentials and also a specific design